# MySQL CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Error

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I'm running EasyPHP 5.4.6 with MySQL 5.5.27-log.

When I try to create a temporary table using the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (x int);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'temp_table' (errno: 22)
```

However, it works if I remove the "TEMPORARY".

The syntax for the temporary table was copied verbatim from an example page.  I tried googling the error numbers, but that yielded nothing I could use.

Can anyone think of what may be going on?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Can you show your mysql configuration file?

Comment: `count` is a reserved word. Try a different column name.

Comment: I am not sure about this:
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (count int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
mysql>

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  It looks like a bug. I really don't want to install a different stack :(

Comment: I'm looking for it.  It's not in my installation folder.  The O/S is WinXP.

Comment: Ok, the search is done.  There is no my.cnf.

Comment: Sorry it's my.ini by default on Windows, C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini

Comment: Ok, found the my.ini in my mysql folder.  Looking at the file now.  It's hefty so it may be best not to post it here.  Is there anything in particular I should look for?  Tried a search for temp and temporary...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20354/discussion-between-user1161318-and-jonathan-amend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

errno: 22 indicates that MySQL is trying to access a file with an invalid path (fopen -> INVAL). MySQL is not likely to generate an invalid path, so check that your temp path is set correctly. If you have a custom set tmpdir in your MySQL configuration, make sure it's a valid path. If not, check the current value using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%tmp%'`; If something is incorrect or missing, check that your system's TEMP environment variable is set properly. For more info, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/temporary-files.html.

Comment: That did the trick.  The my.ini did not have a tmpdir variable, so I just added one and set it to a path.  Now everything works.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I would still double-check why your system's TEMP path is not set properly though; this might cause you further headaches in the future.

Comment: Once I get the chance, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user you are using has the `create_tmp_table_priv` privelege granted (table `user` of the `mysql` database)

Comment: The user does.  The user is root :).  But I also manually checked the privilege table just in case.