# Can't create table '<table name>' (errno: 22)

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following:

```
Can't create table 'tempabcd' (errno: 22)
```

This error occurs after the following query (simplified) has run several thousands of times

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempabcd;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabcd (id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MyISAM; 
INSERT INTO tempabcd VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3');
Select id from tempabcd
Union
Select id from othertable
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempabcd;
```

The query runs fine in the beginning but for some reason it fails after some time. When the error occurs all new queries return the same error.

I have read [MySQL CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635450/mysql-create-temporary-table-error) which says that Error 22 is due to MySQL attempting to access a file with an invalid path, however in this case this query runs successfully several thousand times before I encounter this error - how can this be the case if the temporary path is set incorrectly?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635450/mysql-create-temporary-table-error?

Comment: Yes i read this question but since the error only occurs after it has run successfully for many times i do not think it is a problem with the path set in the my.ini file.

Comment: I assume that the temp path is on a local filesystem?

Comment: `When the error occurs all new queries return the same error.` - can you, at that point, attach [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) to the mysql server process to see what path is actually not found?

Comment: I assume that the temp path is on a local filesystem = yes.
I am not familiar with strace is StraceNT the windows equivalent for strace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what was causing this problem. In some rare cases the created temporary table would not contain any rows and the following sql is executed:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempabcd;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabcd (id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE=MyISAM; 
INSERT INTO tempabcd VALUES ();
..... 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempabcd;
```

This generates an error but the temporary table is created and not dropped. Then after this error has occured often enough the open file limit is reached and the error

```
Can't create table '<table name>' (errno: 22)
```

is returned. Preventing the query from inserting 0 records has solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

ERRNO: 22 means that MySQL is trying to access a file with an invalid path. MySQL is not likely to generate an invalid path, so you need to check that your temp path is set correctly.

For more info, check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/temporary-files.html.

Also check these lines:-

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempabcd (id int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id)) .........
INSERT INTO tempabcd VALUES ('1','2','3'); <-- Passing 3 values here
```

Comment: Typo in the sql sorry. The error only occurs after the query has run thousands of times successfully. So how can the path all of a sudden become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

in the 3rd line of the query you are passing 3 values so you will get

**
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1  **